# ionic 3 angular slide height just enough to hold contents

Tags: angular, ionic3, ion-slides

my page currently looks like http://moblize.it

and i am trying to change the slide height to be just enough to the contents. obviously cannot fix it else it will screw up on smaller devices

the current code looks like

```
 <ion-slides direction="vertical" speed="1000" slidesPerView="1">
  <ion-slide  class="site-slide"  style="background-color:#2298D3">
    <ion-card style="height:300px;float:center">
      <img src="http://www.segalpetroniru.com/images/Consulting-Services-Hero-Image-Secondary.jpg" />
    </ion-card>
  </ion-slide>

  <ion-slide padding class="site-slide" >
     <ion-row>
       <ion-col text-left>
         <ion-row><ion-col col-1 style="background-color: #4054B2"></ion-col><ion-col padding style="color:#616161"><h2 style="color:#616161">Revolution!</h2>

In the field of Mobile App Development!</ion-col>
         </ion-row>
       </ion-col>
     <ion-col text-left>
      <ion-row><ion-col col-1 style="background-color: #4054B2"></ion-col><ion-col padding style="color:#616161">
              <h2 style="color:#616161">Bots!</h2>
              It's time for conversational apps. You need conversations, you need apps, you need everything!</ion-col>
         </ion-row>
     </ion-col>
     </ion-row>

  </ion-slide>

  <ion-slide class="site-slide" style="background-color: #F5F5F5" padding>
        <ion-row><ion-col col-1></ion-col><ion-col>
        <ion-card padding>
        <div style="background-color:#2298D3;color:white;height:50px;font-weight:bold;font-size:large" text-left padding>Contact Us</div>
       <ion-list class="contact-form" padding>
            <form [formGroup]="slideTwoForm" style="background-color: #D9E4EE">

                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label floating>Name</ion-label>
                    <ion-input formControlName="username" type="text"></ion-input>
                </ion-item>

                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label floating>Company</ion-label>
                    <ion-input formControlName="company" type="text"></ion-input>
                </ion-item>

                 <ion-item>
                    <ion-label floating>Email</ion-label>
                    <ion-input formControlName="email" type="email"></ion-input>
                </ion-item>

                 <ion-item>
                    <ion-label floating>Phone</ion-label>
                    <ion-input formControlName="phone" type="text"></ion-input>
                </ion-item>

                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label floating>Message</ion-label>
                    <ion-textarea formControlName="message"></ion-textarea>
                </ion-item>

            </form>
             <button ion-button full color="site" (click)="sendMessage()" [disabled]="formIncomplete() == true">Send</button>
        </ion-list>     
        </ion-card>  
        </ion-col><ion-col col-1></ion-col></ion-row>
  </ion-slide>

</ion-slides>
```

Comment: Will the contents just be that image? because then you can use `background-size:cover` otherwise you are going to maybe want to look into flexbox stuff

Comment: no it can have other ionic components other than images